# "XMLCommand.initialize failed: java.lang.NullPointerException" when using dataset-proxy in a workflow databroker

Tags: aviarc

I'm creating a workflow databroker, and in the pre-workflow I am using a `dataset-proxy` to iterate over the populate-dataset. However I get the following error when I compile:

```
XMLCommand.initialize failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
at nz.co.aviarc.xml.command.dataset.DatasetProxy.initialize(DatasetProxy.java:35)
at com.aviarc.framework.xml.command.XMLCommandElementImpl.finalize(XMLCommandElementImpl.java:90)
at com.aviarc.framework.xml.compilation.XMLSAXHandler.endElement(XMLSAXHandler.java:336)
at net.sf.saxon.event.ContentHandlerProxy.endElement(ContentHandlerProxy.java:391)
at net.sf.saxon.event.NamespaceReducer.endElement(NamespaceReducer.java:213)
at net.sf.saxon.event.ReceivingContentHandler.endElement(ReceivingContentHandler.java:443)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:598)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:673)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1645)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:875)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1198)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:564)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:404)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:193)
at net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:30)
at com.aviarc.framework.xml.compilation.AviarcXMLResourceCompiler.compile(AviarcXMLResourceCompiler.java:137)
...
```

I get exactly the same error even when I use the code example straight out of the documentation (com.aviarc.dataset:1.1.0):

```xml
<workflow xmlns:ds="urn:aviarc:xmlcommand:com.aviarc.dataset">
    <ds:dataset-proxy dataset="ds" proxyname="dsproxy">
        <set-current-row dataset="dsproxy" position="2" />
        <set-field field="dsproxy.email" value="test@test.com" />
    </ds:dataset-proxy>
</workflow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the documentation is wrong, as `proxyname` is not a valid attribute on `dataset-proxy`. I didn't see it at first (because of the huge stack trace) but I was also getting this warning:

```
Unknown attribute 'proxyname'
```

**The correct attribute is `name`, not `proxyname`.** Changing this resolved the error.

Comment: Did you raise a bug for that?

Comment: @Vlad not yet, but I plan to.